# Pyspark dataframe column(type string) split and take out 5th postion value

Tags: python, dataframe

`data_str = (df
           .select(df.withColumn('column1',split(df['column1'],',').getItem(4)),
            df.column2.alias('column2'))
            )`

```
column1 = '"gh","dfg","jsd","shj","wyw","djg"'
```

From the above code, I want the 5th position value from the column1 field.
I am using the piece of code above and getting an error **"Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame[product_code: string, variation_number: int, data_string: string] of type . For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.**
"
Please give me your suggestions about what is going wrong.

Comment: What version of spark are you using?

Comment: version 2.3.0.cloudera3,  Using Python version 2.7.12

Comment: I don't think you can use getItem().

Comment: split_data = split(df.col,',')
data_str_df = (df
                       .select(regexp_replace(split_data.getItem(4),'\"','').alias('colname'),
                                   col('filed1').alias('field2'))
                           )                                                                                                                         I got the solution by doing above.